# Assign event to button from external library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert, alertify

Every time I press a button, there is a random chance that a alertify alert window popups. The alertify alert popup is something I use instead of javascript Alert, just to get a nicer design.

[Alertify library](http://alertifyjs.org/)

And here is a screenshot of the current situation:

[image]

I want to assign a event to the OK button. When I use the "inspect element" function in google chrome, I see that this green OK button has an id called "alertify-ok", so I want to assign an event when this button is pressed.

I've tried to add this part to my HTML document in the script part:

```
$( "#alertify-ok" ).on( "click",function() {alert("finally");});
```

But nothing happens. The reason why I need this to work, is that the youtube popupmodal should come up right after I've pressed the OK button. I belive the error comes because the alertify window with HTML is from an external library, so how can i do this?

Comment: You should be able to access the button element, even if it is from an external library, unless it is contained within an `iframe`. Can you check if the alert is creating an `iframe`?

Comment: Also, when are you registering this click event? If the button does not exist at the time when you register the event, it won't work.

Comment: You need a document-ready clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alerts and the others take callback functions on creation, https://github.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/blob/0.3.12/src/js/alertify.js#L608. You don't need to attach another event listener, just give it the function you want it to execute. example below:

```
alertify.alert("alerttext", function(e) {
    functionIWantToCall();
});
```

Comment: Okey, so I can just write: alertify.alert("alerttext", functionIWantToCall())?

Comment: sorry, actually i've been testing it out and you would need to do it like the example above in the edited answer

Comment: Actually, the better way is `alertify.alert("alerttext", functionIWantToCall)`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the event on an element you know is already existent (like "body") and specify it to trigger only when the wanted element is clicked:

```
$(" body").on({
    click: function () {...
    }
}, "#trigger");
```